# how to pass context to serailizers from APIView in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

i tried to get context in serializes from APIView,
how to pass context to serailizers from APIView in django rest framework

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking but you can try `context ={key:value}` `serializer = SerializerName(data=request.data, context=context)` in apiview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you pass the context to the serializer, if you are instantiating it manually.

`serializer = MySerializer(data=data, context={'request': 'format': self.format_kwarg, self.request, 'view': self})`

Of course you can add any other data needed in your serializers to the context dictionary, but it typically contains the request object, view and format